# ListView with custom adapter: some items are hidden

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-adapter

I have a ListView with a custom adapter, but when scroll in ListView some items are hidden: [image]

From the image you can see  that from a69 jumps to a72 leaving hidden items a70 and a71.

Here is the code of the custom adapter:

```
public NewCurrenciesAdapter(ArrayList<NewCurrencyData> list, Context context) {
    m_list = list;
    m_context = context;
    m_layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return m_list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return m_list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = m_layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.addcurrency_item, parent, false);
    }

    TextView currencyName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textCurrencyName);
    currencyName.setText("a" + position);

    ImageView currencyImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageCurrencyCountry);

    currencyImage.setImageResource(getImageId(m_context, "c" + m_list.get(position).name.toLowerCase()));

    if (m_list.get(position).checked) {
        convertView.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.holo_green_dark);
    }
    else {
        convertView.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.background_light);
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

EDIT: Here are the layout of activity:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListViewAllCurrencies"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.8">
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Apply"
            android:id="@+id/buttonAdd"
            android:layout_weight=".50"
            android:onClick="applyChange"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:id="@+id/buttonCancel"
            android:layout_weight=".50"
            android:onClick="cancelChange"/>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

And the addcurrency_item:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageCurrencyCountry"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/cusd"
        android:contentDescription="" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textCurrencyName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="Currency name"/>
    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Sounds like u have the problem in layout file. Share the layout file having listview and the buttons.

Comment: If you are using relative layout then set your listview like layout_above = "@+id/button layout id".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

debug the int returned by `getImageId(m_context, "c" + m_list.get(position).name.toLowerCase()`

It is probably returning 0 or -1 which does not set images in your imageview and the view is collapsed!

Comment: Thanks! Commenting the lines with ImageView resolved the problem.